# Python - keeping the last n values of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
         Date       Open       High        Low      Close  Adj Close   Volume
0  2010-01-04  22.453505  22.625179  22.267525  22.389128  20.755877  3815500
1  2010-01-05  22.324749  22.331903  22.002861  22.145924  20.530411  4186000
2  2010-01-06  22.067240  22.174536  22.002861  22.067240  20.457466  3243700
3  2010-01-07  22.017168  22.045780  21.816881  22.038626  20.430946  3095100
4  2010-01-08  21.917025  22.067240  21.745350  22.031473  20.424318  3733900
```

and I want to keep the last 250 or 500 etc (depending on the value of the offset) using this code:

```
def positive_return_days(portfolio,offset):
    positive_returns = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['ticker', 'name', 'total positive', 'total days','percentage of positive days'])
    for asset in portfolio:
        print(asset.head())
        print("1. Asset name: ", asset.name)
        asset = asset.tail(offset)
        print("2. Asset name: ", asset.name)
        total_positive_days = (asset.Close - asset.Close.shift(1) > 0).sum()
        total_days = len(asset.index)
        percentage_of_positive_days = float(total_positive_days/total_days)
        print("count",(asset.Close - asset.Close.shift(1) > 0).sum())
        new_row = {'ticker':asset.name, 'name':asset.name, 'total positive':total_positive_days, 'total days':total_days,"percentage of positive days":percentage_of_positive_days}
        positive_returns = positive_returns.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
        print("Asset: ", asset.name, "total positive days: ", total_positive_days, "total days:",len(asset.index),"percentage of positive days",percentage_of_positive_days)
    print(positive_returns.nlargest(50, 'percentage of positive days')[
                  ['ticker','percentage of positive days','total positive', 'total days']])
    print(positive_returns.loc[positive_returns['ticker']=='AAPL'])
    return positive_returns
```

but I am getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
```

after I use the tail function. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows I assume ?  This seems a bit more complicated then necessary -- let me try to rewrite this.  For your question:

```
df.tail(250)
```

is obvious choice, or

```
df.iloc[-250:-1]
```

also, the issue is in regard to name, I would try writing it out in pd

```
df['name']['close']
```

rather than df.name.close  -- this syntax can sometimes get you into trouble.

For the problem --

I would just build this out with new columns.
it's hard to do this without your actual dataset, but I would just add new columns, for ex.

```
df['up_days'] = np.where(df['name']['close'] > df['name']['close'].shift(1),1,0).cumsum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.tail(250)
```

This will keep the last 250 rows of the dataframe. No more code needed.

As an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'day_1': [0,1,1,0,1,1,0], 'day_2': [0,0,1,1,1,1,0], 'day_3': [0,1,1,1,0,0,0], 'day_4': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0], 'day_5': [0,0,1,1,1,0,0]})

   day_1  day_2  day_3  day_4  day_5
0      0      0      0      0      0
1      1      0      1      1      0
2      1      1      1      0      1
3      0      1      1      1      1
4      1      1      0      0      1
5      1      1      0      1      0
6      0      0      0      0      0

df.tail(3)

   day_1  day_2  day_3  day_4  day_5
4      1      1      0      0      1
5      1      1      0      1      0
6      0      0      0      0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested in seeing the full output.  According to your code, `portfolio` should be a `DataFrame` type object, with the attribute `name` available. If `portfolio` is of the data that you show, it does not contain a `name` attribute. That would explain the error that you are seeing.

Comment: see columns = ['name', ...] -- changed column names.